# Cannot run solr (cannot open log file)

Tags: java, solr, redhat, sudo, bin

Been trying to get [solr](http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/lucene/solr/6.0.0/) running for a while now... finally seemed like I got it. Following [this](http://yonik.com/solr-tutorial/) tutorial. Ran this command

```
bin/solr start
```

And saw this text

```
Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983
```

But then...

```
Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
tail: cannot open `/root/downloads/solr-6.0.0/server/logs/solr.log' for reading: No such file or directory
```

This is getting highly frustrating. I tried to run the bin command with sudo, still no luck. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT : I ran it in the foreground with

```
bin/solr start -f
```

and got this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/start/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:296)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:406)
```

My java-foo is not up to par, so I have no idea what to make of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to update to java 1.8
[This](http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/) was useful

Comment: Same here. Updating exactly to 1.8 solved. Initially I had downloaded the later version (java 10) which was causing the issue. Thanks @Zack!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. Make sure these are set

> java -version

outputs

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

and

> echo $JAVA_HOME

outputs

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Note: The minor version of java and java home path may change from system to system. But make sure they are of the same version(Java 8).

Please check your /var/solr/logs/solr_gc.log and see which version of java it has used to install/start solr. 
In my case, though these parameters were set, it was using java 7. So I uninstalled java 7 and started solr again. It started working

> Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [/]
>   Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=11983). Happy searching!

Answer (score 2):

This issue could be related to RAM size on Solr node. If you are running Solr on VM with small RAM size, enabling swap or increasing RAM should resolve this.

Comment: I was skeptical of this solution but I did enable SWAP on my virtual server and in fact, it did work. Very weird though.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently changed the heap size in solr.in.sh file with values

> SOLR_HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx12g

but afterwards solr failed to start. Tried to follow the solutions provided by others but no luck.
Then looked into log file located at: /var/solr/logs/solr-**port**-console.log which gave me following error:

> Invalid initial heap size: -Xms-Xms1g -Xmx12g
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

So, I changed the value of SOLR_HEAP in solr.in.sh file to "12g" which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the memory is low, you can run solr with the following command:

bin/solr restart -p 9983 -s "xxx_home" -m 4g -force

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

For Solr 6 there is a bug where Jetty will not load with a java version containing a 9.  [details](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/alfresco-solr-6-6-5-not-start-invalid-version-of-java-11-0-9-1/td-p/303901)

I found more information about the error in the file /var/solr/logs/solr-8983-console.log